# Debugging dispatching in the middle of a dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

```
Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.
```

I've come across the problem a number of times, and am looking for a better way to debug this problem.  Is there a way to log the queue of dispatched actions to see which action is apparently being dispatched?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Chrome to run and debug your applications? If so, see this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-exceptions

If you use webpack or something to bundle your javascript, you should have source mapping in development that lets you actually see what lines in your original source are being called.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it's a bit harder when debugging a dispatcher error inside the entire React library.  My question was geared more to the debugging the specific error I had.